# Can't select json elements added dynamically with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to make a simple cross-fade slider but this time with images retrieved from a json file and added dynamically to a container.

I can easily get all pictures with all the information inside the json file but as soon as I have to select them later I can't. It's like they are not there. It's not the first time I add dynamically a html element. I use really often `.append()` or `.prepend()` and I can as easily find their children once they are created.

So I have a div in which I load dynamically some images. I want to pick them up again (not from the json file this time, but from the dom) so I can make a slider plugin with them.

```
$.fn.slider = function(options) {
  var picstore, $fig,
  def   = {
    json: undefined,
    dataName: 'jsonslider'
  },
  cfg   = $.extend( true, def, options ),
  store = cfg.json,
  dataN = cfg.dataName, 
  $wrap = $( this ),
  $next = $wrap.next();

$.getJSON( store, function( data ) {
  picstore = data.pictures;

  for ( i = 0; i < picstore.length; i++ ) {
    $wrap.append( '<figure data-' + dataN +'="' + i + '"><img src="' + picstore[i].url + '" alt="' + picstore[i].alt + '"/></figure>' );
};
```

I tried everything!

`$fig = $wrap.children()` does not work

`$fig = $( '[data-' + dataN + '="0"]' )` does not work

What do you suggest me to do?

[demo](http://davidedc.altervista.org/my-brand)

[github index.html raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dcdeiv/my-brand/master/index.html)

[github js raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dcdeiv/my-brand/master/slider/slider.js)

[github json raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dcdeiv/my-brand/master/slider/pictures.json)

Comment: you should have `$` this in your `append`: `$wrap.append($('<figure data-'`

Comment: @erkaner it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution.

```
$.getJSON( store, function( data ) {
  var arr = $.map(data, function(el){ return el; });

  for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    $wrap.append($('<figure data-' + dataN +'="' + i + '"><img src="' + arr[i].url + '" alt="' + arr[i].alt + '"/></figure>'));
  };

  var figs = $wrap.children();
  figs.first().addClass( 'slider-active' );
});
```

You can't access json dynamically objects outside the function.